# unable to delete keys with prefix from redis

Tags: redis

How does one deletes keys with certain prefix from Redis 5+?

I've tried following, yet didn't work for me(

```
root@1acb94e11aa2:/data# redis-cli --version
redis-cli 5.0.4
root@1acb94e11aa2:/data# redis-cli -n 9 KEYS ISO:* | wc -l
935
root@1acb94e11aa2:/data# redis-cli -n 9 KEYS ISO:* | xargs -0 redis-cli -n 9 DEL
(integer) 0
root@1acb94e11aa2:/data# redis-cli -n 9 KEYS ISO:* | wc -l
935
root@1acb94e11aa2:/data# redis-cli -n 9 --scan --pattern ISO:* | xargs -0 redis-cli -n 9 unlink
(integer) 0
root@1acb94e11aa2:/data#
```

Please advise.

Comment: What's `unlink`? I think you want `del`.

Comment: @MarkSetchell `UNLINK` is the new and improved `DEL` (async)

Comment: @ItamarHaber Ok, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

As long as your key names do not include spaces, you should be able to run this:

```
$ redis-cli -n 9 --scan --pattern "ISO:*" | xargs -n 1 redis-cli -n 9 UNLINK
```

EDIT: if they do include spaces, you can do:

```
$ redis-cli -n 9 --scan --pattern "ISO:*" | xargs -n 1 -d "\n" redis-cli -n 9 UNLINK
```

Comment: keys includes space

Answer (score 0):

FIX:

```
root@1acb94e11aa2:/data# redis-cli -n 9 KEYS ISO:* | xargs -d "\n" redis-cli -n 9 del
(integer) 262
root@1acb94e11aa2:/data#
root@1acb94e11aa2:/data# redis-cli -n 9 KEYS ISO:*
(empty list or set)
root@1acb94e11aa2:/data#
```